# tlp power management

Tags: tlp

I have having trouble with tlp power management
I just installed ubuntu 14.04 today

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
```

This two commands worked

```
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo start tlp
```

These commands failed and returned some errors

When I did `sudo tlp start` and got `sudo: tlp: command not found`

When I did `sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw` I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... 
Done 
E: Unable to locate package tlp 
E: Unable to locate package tlp-rdw
```

I have a thinkpad laptop so I also typed this and it worked

```
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms
```

Why can't I run `tlp` when it loaded from the repository seemed to work

Comment: sudo start tlp is wrong. it should be "sudo tlp start"

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I have never tried myself and please do it on your own risk):

```
su

echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu trusty main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 02D65EFF; apt-key adv --keyserver 
pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 02D65EFF

apt-get update

apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

Also you may see these links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149188/unable-to-locate-package-tlp-during-tlp-installation

http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#install-config

https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: OK I did sudo tlp start and got sudo: tlp: command not found

Comment: When i did sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw I got this error:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tlp
E: Unable to locate package tlp-rdw

Comment: On what Ubuntu release?

Comment: 14.04 ubuntu trusty

Comment: Ill try the su echo command when I get the chance . Ill report back when done.