# THinkpad p50 running hot on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cpu, fan, fancontrol

I have recently got a thinkpad p50s and put Ubuntu 16.04 on it. The fan is constantly running even when i am just browsing the internet. [Output from Psensou](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfOjl.png)

Comment: Ubuntu by default does not install much in the way of power management.  Please try `sudo apt install tlp` to install a base set of power mangement tools (you should edit '/etc/default/tlp' to customize tlp for your application)

Answer (score 1):

Installing [TLP – Linux Advanced Power Management](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html) may help by managing resources used by your machine.

See [tlp power management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560225/tlp-power-management) for installation instructions, but here they are for convenience:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo start tlp
```

Additionally, you can also install the following for your ThinkPad.

- Battery charge thresholds – ThinkPads only
- Recalibrate battery – ThinkPads only

These may provide additional help with your fan problem by managing battery charging (which may be contributing to heat in your laptop chassis).

You can install these optional packages using:

```
sudo apt install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms
```